# Calcite SqlParser fails on "int(11)" data-type specification in CREATE TABLE statement using MYSQL_5 conformance

Tags: apache-calcite

I have a project that requires using Calcite's SQL Parser to parse large amounts of DDL statements which are in heavy MySQL dialect.

I have isolated an issue which can be illustrated with this specific example:

```
create table `t1` (x int(11))
```

The astute reader may recognize `int(11)` is MySQL dialect. I need to be able to parse this. Removing the `(11)` in this example is not an acceptable fix.

Here's a Java JUnit test that reproduces the problem:

```
public class SqlParserMysqlTest {

    private static final Config CONFIG = SqlParser.Config.DEFAULT
        .withLex(Lex.MYSQL).withConformance(SqlConformanceEnum.MYSQL_5)
        .withParserFactory(SqlDdlParserImpl.FACTORY);

    @Test
    public void testMysqlCreate() throws SqlParseException {
        SqlParser sqlParser = SqlParser.create(
                new SourceStringReader("create table `t1` (x int(11))"), CONFIG);
        SqlNode sqlNode = sqlParser.parseQuery();

        Assert.assertEquals(SqlKind.CREATE_TABLE, sqlNode.getKind());

        SqlCreateTable create = (SqlCreateTable) sqlNode;
        Assert.assertEquals("T1", create.name.getSimple());
        final SqlColumnDeclaration sqlColumnDeclaration = (SqlColumnDeclaration) create.columnList
                .get(0);
        Assert.assertEquals("X", sqlColumnDeclaration.name.getSimple());
        Assert.assertEquals("INTEGER",
                sqlColumnDeclaration.dataType.getTypeName().getSimple());
    }

}
```

POM dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.calcite</groupId>
        <artifactId>calcite-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.26.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.calcite</groupId>
        <artifactId>calcite-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.26.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The issue is that the parser barfs on the parenthesis in `int(11)`:

```
org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParseException: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 25.
Was expecting one of:
    "ARRAY" ...
    "AS" ...
    "DEFAULT" ...
    "GENERATED" ...
    "MULTISET" ...
    "NOT" ...
    "NULL" ...
    ")" ...
    "," ...
    
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.ddl.SqlDdlParserImpl.convertException(SqlDdlParserImpl.java:394)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.ddl.SqlDdlParserImpl.normalizeException(SqlDdlParserImpl.java:157)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.handleException(SqlParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.parseQuery(SqlParser.java:155)
```

I know that [other people](https://twitter.com/julianhyde/status/1315434045782728705) are successfully using Calcite to parse MySQL syntax, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html#tableElement) on table elements, it looks like the corrected syntax could be `` create table `t1` (x int 11) `` (losing the internal parentheses) but I have no way to test it.